# What is considered "small" object in Go regarding stack allocation?

Tags: go, slice, allocation, escape-analysis

The code:

```
func MaxSmallSize() {
    a := make([]int64, 8191)
    b := make([]int64, 8192)
    _ = a
    _ = b
}
```

Then run `go build -gcflags='-m' . 2>&1` to check memory allocation details. The result:

```
./mem.go:10: can inline MaxSmallSize
./mem.go:12: make([]int64, 8192) escapes to heap
./mem.go:11: MaxSmallSize make([]int64, 8191) does not escape
```

**My question is why `a` is small object and `b` is large object?**

`make` 64KB will escape to heap and less will allocate in stack. Does the `_MaxSmallSize = 32 << 10` is the reason?

`go env`

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/vagrant/gopath"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/home/vagrant/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/home/vagrant/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build201775001=/tmp/go-build"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Comment: This is implementation dependent, different compilers might do it differently, different architectures might do it differently and different releases may handle it differently. So what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 3):

Since this is not mentioned in the language spec, it is an implementation detail, and as such, it may vary based on a number of things (Go version, target OS, architecture etc.).

If you want to find out its current value or a place to start digging, check out the `cmd/compile/internal/gc` package.

The [escape analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis) which decides where to allocate the variable is in [`cmd/compile/internal/gc/esc.go`](https://golang.org/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/esc.go). Check of the make slice operation is in unexported function `esc()`:

```
func esc(e *EscState, n *Node, up *Node) {
    // ...

    // Big stuff escapes unconditionally
    // "Big" conditions that were scattered around in walk have been gathered here
    if n.Esc != EscHeap && n.Type != nil &&
        (n.Type.Width > MaxStackVarSize ||
            (n.Op == ONEW || n.Op == OPTRLIT) && n.Type.Elem().Width >= 1<<16 ||
            n.Op == OMAKESLICE && !isSmallMakeSlice(n)) {
        if Debug['m'] > 2 {
            Warnl(n.Lineno, "%v is too large for stack", n)
        }
        n.Esc = EscHeap
        addrescapes(n)
        escassignSinkNilWhy(e, n, n, "too large for stack") // TODO category: tooLarge
    }

    // ...
}
```

The decision involving the size is in function `isSmallMakeSlice()`, this is in file [`cmd/compile/internal/gc/walk.go`](https://golang.org/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/walk.go):

```
func isSmallMakeSlice(n *Node) bool {
    if n.Op != OMAKESLICE {
        return false
    }
    l := n.Left
    r := n.Right
    if r == nil {
        r = l
    }
    t := n.Type

    return Smallintconst(l) && Smallintconst(r) && (t.Elem().Width == 0 || r.Int64() < (1<<16)/t.Elem().Width)
}
```

The size limit is this:

```
r.Int64() < (1<<16)/t.Elem().Width
```

`r` is the length or capacity of the slice (if cap is provided), `t.Elem().Width` is the byte size of the element type:

```
NumElem < 65536 / SizeElem
```

In your case:

```
NumElem < 65536 / 8 = 8192
```

So if the slice type is `[]uint64`, 8192 is the limit from which it is allocated on the heap (instead of the stack), just as you experienced.

Answer (score 3):

@icza's answer is really insightful, I'd just like to add that the link is a bit outdated 5 years later, you can find the code in [cmd/compile/internal/escape/utils.go](https://go.dev/src/cmd/compile/internal/escape/utils.go) and in turn [cmd/compile/internal/ir/cfg.go](https://go.dev/src/cmd/compile/internal/ir/cfg.go) now:

```golang
// HeapAllocReason returns the reason the given Node must be heap
// allocated, or the empty string if it doesn't.
func HeapAllocReason(n ir.Node) string {
    // ... omitted for brevity
    if n.Op() == ir.OMAKESLICE {
        n := n.(*ir.MakeExpr)
        r := n.Cap
        if r == nil {
            r = n.Len
        }
        if !ir.IsSmallIntConst(r) {
            return "non-constant size"
        }
        if t := n.Type(); t.Elem().Size() != 0 && ir.Int64Val(r) > ir.MaxImplicitStackVarSize/t.Elem().Size() {
            return "too large for stack"
        }
    }

    return ""
}
```

and `ir.MaxImplicitStackVarSize` is:

```golang
package ir

var (
    // maximum size of implicit variables that we will allocate on the stack.
    //   p := new(T)          allocating T on the stack
    //   p := &T{}            allocating T on the stack
    //   s := make([]T, n)    allocating [n]T on the stack
    //   s := []byte("...")   allocating [n]byte on the stack
    // Note: the flag smallframes can update this value.
    MaxImplicitStackVarSize = int64(64 * 1024)
)
```